# I am having issues with the user name cannot be null error

Tags: twilio

I am using intellij for Java and I keep getting the error user name can not be null. I have tried using my authetication information including my account sid and auth token but I still get this error:

[image: image of the code I'm following. Personal information is removed]

Any help is greatly appreciated and any guidance is also appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It looks like, since you have blocked it out in your image, that you are calling `System.getenv` with your actual account Sid and auth token and that is returning `null` for both.

Instead, you should [set your account sid and your auth token in the environment](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/01/how-to-set-environment-variables.html), calling them `TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID` and `TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN`, then load them like this:

```java
public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = System.getenv("TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID");
public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = System.getenv("TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN");
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is seen from the screenshot, the username and password are already null before passing it to Twilio. You are using System.getenv(). Make sure that it pulls username and password environment variables properly.
It might also be that the environment variables are not set.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use System.getenv(), directly enter your sid and auth token as string.